# Create a pandas Dataframe based on a dictionary which summarizes hierarchy between categories

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary :

```
hierarchy = {
'Category1': [],
'Category2': ['Category1'],
'Category3': ['Category1'],
'Category4': ['Category2'],
'Category5': ['Category4'],
'Category6': ['Category4'],
'Category7': ['Category6']}
```

This dictionary summarizes which category is a sub-category of a parent category. For example, Category2 is a sub-category of Category1. Similarly, Category3 is a sub-category of Category1. Category4 is a sub-category of Category2, Category5 is a sub-category of Category4, and so on.

I'd like a function that could summarize these informations in a dataframe, and link all the sub-categories together. For example, thanks to the previous dictionary, we know that Category5 is a sub-category of Category4, Category4 is a sub-category of Category2, and Category2 is a sub-category of Category1. I'd like to have the information on the same row, where each column contains the categories of the hierarchy in descending order of size.

In the example of the hierarchy dictionary, I'd like to have the following output:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Biggest_category' : ['Category1','Category1','Category1'],
    'Second_Biggest_category': ['Category2','Category2','Category3'],
    'Third_Biggest_category': ['Category4','Category4',[]],
    'Fourth_Biggest_category': ['Category5','Category6',[]],
    'Fifth_Biggest_category': [[],'Category7',[]]
})
```

Can someone helps me please? I have tried many things but nothing really work as I would like.

Comment: Is there a reason you want 3 items in each list?

Comment: No, it's just an example. I want the number of items I need, it doesn't have to be a specific number

Comment: Could you edit your post to show exactly what you want, please?

Answer (score 0):

First, get parent nodes and their children:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# Use defauldict to initialize a dictionary with empty lists as values
nodes = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in hierarchy.items():
    if value:
        nodes[value[0]].append(key)
nodes = dict(nodes)

print(nodes)
# Output

{'Category1': ['Category2', 'Category3'],
 'Category2': ['Category4'],
 'Category4': ['Category5', 'Category6'],
 'Category6': ['Category7']}
```

Then, traverse the nodes in a [recursive](https://realpython.com/python-recursion/) fashion:

```py
def traverse(start, nodes):
    if start not in nodes:
        return [start]
    paths = []
    for child in nodes[start]:
        for path in traverse(child, nodes):
            paths.append(start + "," + path)
    return paths


categories = pd.DataFrame([path.split(",") for path in traverse("Category1", nodes)])
```

Finally:

```py
print(categories)
# Output

           0          1          2          3          4
0  Category1  Category2  Category4  Category5       None
1  Category1  Category2  Category4  Category6  Category7
2  Category1  Category3       None       None       None
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly ! But I have just found another problem on my dictionary hierarchy... Could you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530115/create-a-hierarchy-between-categories