# Create a hierarchy between categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have this following dataframe :

```
pandas_test=pd.DataFrame(data={'TAGS': [['Category1','Category2','Category3'],
                                                           ['Category2','Category4'],
                                                            ['Category5','Category4'],
                                                               ['Category5','Category4','Category6','Category8'],
                                                               ['Category1','Category2'],
                                                               ['Category2','Category3']]})
```

I try to find the parent of each category. To explain how it should work : a categoryA on the left and of the same row of another categoryB would be his parent. So in the case of pandas_test, I would like this result :

```
 {'Category1': None, ‘Category2': 'Category1', 'Category3': 'Category2’, 'Category4': 'Category2', 'Category5': None, 'Category4’: 'Category5’, 'Category6’: 'Category4’, 'Category8’: 'Category6’}.
```

Here, Category1 doesn't have a parent, Category2 has Category1 as a parent, Category3 has Category2, etc...

For the moment, I have the following code :

```
category_counts = {}
for index, row in pandas_test.iterrows():
    #categories = row['TAGS'][0].split(',') if row['TAGS'] else []
    categories = row['TAGS']
    for i in range(len(categories)):
        category = categories[i].strip()
        if category not in category_counts:
            category_counts[category] = {'count': 1, 'subcategories': set()}
        else:
            category_counts[category]['count'] += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, len(categories)):
            subcategory = categories[j].strip()
            category_counts[category]['subcategories'].add(subcategory)

# Analyze category_counts dictionary to determine hierarchy
hierarchy = {}
for category, data in category_counts.items():
    subcategories = data['subcategories']
    for subcategory in subcategories:
        if subcategory in category_counts:
            if category not in category_counts[subcategory]['subcategories']:
                hierarchy[subcategory] = category

# Apply hierarchy to categories
for category, parent in hierarchy.items():
    if parent in hierarchy:
        hierarchy[category] = hierarchy[parent]
print(hierarchy)
```

But this code returns me this following result :

```
{'Category3': 'Category1', 'Category2': 'Category1', 'Category4': 'Category5', 'Category6': 'Category5', 'Category8': 'Category5'}
```

Category3 should have Category2 as a parent. Of course Category1 is a parent of Category3 aswell because Category1 is a parent of Category2 and Category2 is the parent of Category3, but I want the closest parent (so same for Category 6 and 8 having Category5 as a parent). Also, I want Category4 being the son of Category2 AND Category5.

Can someone helps me please?

Comment: Your desired output is not possible, as python dicts MUST have unique keys. In your example, `Category4` is a key twice.

Comment: Oh yeh @Quantum you right, thank you for noticing that. But is it not possible to have it into a pandas dataframe then for example?

Comment: a pandas dataframe would definitely be possible, just not with the category names as indexes (those also have to be unique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a graph problem, use a specialized library like [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to build a directed graph and get the [`predecessors`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html) of each node:

```
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx
from itertools import pairwise

G = nx.from_edgelist([edge for l in pandas_test['TAGS']
                      for edge in pairwise(l)],
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)

out = {n: list(G.predecessors(n)) for n in G}

print(out)
```

*NB. on python <3.10 you can replace `pairwise(l)` by `zip(l, l[1:])`.*

Output:

```
{'Category1': [],
 'Category2': ['Category1'],
 'Category3': ['Category2'],
 'Category4': ['Category2', 'Category5'],
 'Category5': [],
 'Category6': ['Category4'],
 'Category8': ['Category6']}
```

As a DataFrame:

```
df_out = (pd.Series(out).explode()
            .rename_axis('Child').reset_index(name='Parent')
          )
```

Output:

```
       Child     Parent
0  Category1        NaN
1  Category2  Category1
2  Category3  Category2
3  Category4  Category2
4  Category4  Category5
5  Category5        NaN
6  Category6  Category4
7  Category8  Category6
```

The graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Sorry to ask you again, but now I'm trying to use the code you send me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465689/dynamic-pandas-dataframe/76465910?noredirect=1#comment134936310_76465910 with that new df_out. And I have the following error : NetworkXNoPath: No path between Category5 and Category3. I'm completely fine with the fact that Category5 and Category3 are not linked between each other (if it was like that, then it would be a mistake). However I still want the code to work

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method to achieve your output.

```
result_dict = {} 

for tags in pandas_test['TAGS']:
    for i, category in enumerate(tags):
        if i > 0:
            result_dict[category] = tags[i - 1]
        else:
            result_dict[category] = None
            

for tags in pandas_test['TAGS']:
    for i, category in enumerate(tags):
        if i > 0 and tags[i - 1] not in result_dict:
            result_dict[tags[i - 1]] = None
print(result_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's way better, but I still miss the following information : 'Category4’: 'Category5’, because Category4 is the son of Category2 AND Category5. However, I just realized it's not possible to have the same key twice, but could I have it on a pandas df for example?

Comment: Hi Mop,
Edited the code. could you try it now.

Comment: I have the following error : NameError: name 'category_dict' is not defined. You want me to add category_dict = {} before the for boucles ? If yes, the result of your code is : {}

Comment: Mop,
I changed the dict named as result_dict. check it now